# Extract Data as per to certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building a project where I have to get users with certain conditions only. I have a dataset with shape (31479, 8).

I have columns like:-

```
Index(['Tweet_ID', 'ID', 'Display_Name', 'User_Name', 'Id_URL', 'Description',
       'Content', 'Description_links'],
      dtype='object')
```

So, my main objective is to get all the users who are having "top {ANY PERCENTAGE} onlyfans" keyword in columns 'Display_Name', 'User_Name', 'Id_URL', 'Description', 'Content'.

Where ANY PERCENTAGE must be any number between 0.01 to 9 %.

for Eg: "top 0.01%", "top 0.02%", "top 0.03%, "top 1%", "top 1.1%" and so on but it should be less than = 9.

I have tried the below workaround:-

```
f1 = ((data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.01%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.02%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.03%")) |

      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.05%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.1%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.2%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.3%")) |

      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 0.7%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 1%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 3%")) |
      (data['Display_Name'].str.contains("top 5%")) |
      
      (data['Description'].str.contains("top 0.01%")) |
      (data['Description'].str.contains("top 0.02%")) |
      (data['Description'].str.contains("top 0.03%")) |
      (data['Description'].str.contains("top 0.05%")) |
      
      (data['Content'].str.contains("top 0.01%")) |
      (data['Content'].str.contains("top 0.02%")) |
      (data['Content'].str.contains("top 0.03%")) |
      (data['Content'].str.contains("top 0.05%")))
```

but not getting the correct data as I am expecting.

[image: This is the result I need. As you can see there are some values with 99% which I don't need. This is when I applied the condition on the disply_name only.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex:

```py
pattern = r'top (?:[0-8]([.,]\d+)?|[.,]\d+)%'

data[
  (data['Display_Name'].str.contains(pattern))
  | (data['Description'].str.contains(pattern))
  | (data['Content'].str.contains(pattern))
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried using this earlier but it's not giving any output. Will try once and see how it goes.

Comment: Are the "top {ANY PERCENTAGE} onlyfans" really supposed to be in *all* columns? Maybe you need to combine your conditions with OR (`|`) instead of AND

Comment: It can be anywhere in these columns. It's not mandatory I tried using OR with your pattern but still getting incorrect data.

Comment: Could you share the first rows of your dataframe? With expected result

Comment: Please share your data as a dataframe constructor (using `to_dict` for instance). Images are the worst.

Comment: I've edited my answer by replacing `&` with `|` and `match` with `contains`. It should at least return some rows given your screenshot

Comment: Also handling cases where leading 0 is omitted (eg .3%) and comma as decimal separator